# Extern Variables in C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, stack, extern

I'm trying to use an extern variable to get data between one of my header files and my main .cpp file. I have a .h file set up just for the external variable. This file is titled externTwo.h:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "symbolTable.h"
#include <stack>
using std::stack;

extern stack<symbolTable*> parentalStack;


#endif
```

and then it should be used in my .cpp :

```
#include "symbolTable.h"
//#include "node.h"
#include <FlexLexer.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include "externals.h"
#include "externTwo.h"
using std::vector;
using namespace std;



int yyparse();
yyFlexLexer scanner;
Node *tree;

extern std::vector<Node*> plantation;
extern std::stack<symbolTable*> parentalStack;

int main ()
{

  symbolTable* base = new symbolTable();
  std::vector<symbolTable*> theTable;
  parentalStack.push(base); //put the top scope in
  theTable.push_back(parentalStack.top());
}
```

And finally in my additional .h file (node.h):

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include "symbolTable.h"
#include "externTwo.h"

using std::string;
using std::endl;
using std::ostream;
using std::vector;
using std::stack;


extern stack<symbolTable*> parentalStack;  



class Node
{ };
#endif
```

Whenever I try to access  the parentalStack in main I receive an "undefined reference to `parentalStack'" error. I'm confused why as I have the extern plantation declared in the same fashion in a separate extern file and am able to access it just fine from within main. I aslo get the same error from within node.h if I try to use parentalStack.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You can think of `extern` as meaning approximately "this symbol will be defined elsewhere".  So you actually need to define it as non-`extern` in one of your cpp files.

Comment: Although if you only have one cpp file, then there's absolutely no reason to be declaring this variable in a header file.

Answer (score 1):

remove the `extern` from the cpp file. That will define it. The `extern` only declares it. Just make sure there's only a single .cpp file that defines it.